# Load JSON Faster in Flex 4

Tags: json, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a Flex application,I am loading a JSON file with more than 40,000 items. Does Flex provide a way to load this file faster?

Answer (score 8):

Target Flash Player 11 and use the new native JSON parse:

```
var obj:Object = JSON.parse( value );
```

http://www.skyript.com/2011/07/json-parsingencoding-with-native-parser.html

[image: JSON performance test]