# How to parse node.js REST api object in ActionScript3

Tags: json, actionscript-3, node.js

I have node.js REST api, which returns following object

```
[
       {
           "word": "word"
       },
       {
           "word": "ability"
       },
       {
           "word": "about"
       }
]
```

Can someone please let me how to parse this object in ActionScript3 SDK4.6

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Like JSON response, you can use as3corelib http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/ library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON parsing is included in the default package.

```
var json:Object = JSON.parse("[{\"word\": \"word\"},{\"word\": \"ability\"},{\"word\": \"about\"}]");
```

[image: json]

Default JSON parsing is much higher performance than as3corelib implementation.

Comment: JSON parsing performance comparison: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816784/load-json-faster-in-flex-4/7817042#7817042