# How I can get number of video views of YouTube video with action script 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I used youtube api for adding to flashapp video from youtube. Now I should add to description - number of video views. How I can do this with youtube api? or js maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Youtube API's JSON format here:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/mwZR65NDRO8?v=2&alt=json

Where mwZR65NDR08 is the video id.

EDIT: How to parse JSON with AS3 here: [How to parse JSON (AS3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840523/how-to-parse-json-as3)