# How to parse JSON in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to build an application in Flash, but I have a problem. I'd like to parse the JSON from an web URL.

**[link: JSON text to parse](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=AIzaSyDo8TNRPz27uQsd7aHOFxLu8lkLP3Wm0jY&part=snippet&id=wTa14Sui7mw)**

I'd like to get the JSON string "title" from here. Is there a way I can do it?

It says `undefined`.

```
var VidDataLoader = new URLLoader();

var VidUrl = "THEURL" + param1.getString(0);

trace(VidUrl)

 VidDataLoader.load( new URLRequest(VidUrl))

VidDataLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, doneit)

function doneit(e:Event){ var myData:Object = JSON.parse(VidDataLoader.data);
```

Comment: Post your code.  Are you getting an error message?  Is the title from your parsing just blank?  I can't tell what the problem actually is from what you've posted here.

Comment: It says undefined var VidDataLoader = new URLLoader();

var VidUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=MYKEY&part=snippet&id=" + param1.getString(0);

trace(VidUrl) var config = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + token; VidDataLoader.load( new URLRequest(VidUrl))

VidDataLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, doneit)

function doneit(e:Event){ var myData:Object = JSON.parse(VidDataLoader.data);

Comment: @CeneJenko Check out the [JSON actionscript 3 language reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html#includeExamplesSummary)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON (AS3)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840523/how-to-parse-json-as3)

Comment: Try adding data types eg: `var VidUrl : String = ...etc` and `var VidDataLoader : URLLoader = new ...etc`. Also remember that variables declared inside functions only exist to that function. So try to declare most vars outside of & use function's to update the var.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reach the data from the VidDataLoader class, but the loaded data is part of the event object:

```
public function JSONLoader() {
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, decodeJSON);
    loader.load(new URLRequest("myfile.json"));
}

// use the event to get the data
private function decodeJSON(e:Event):void {
    var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target) ;
    var jsonObject:Object = JSON.parse(loader.data);
}
```